# Hide value from list using checkbox mysql and php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox

I have the checkboxes in the backend and file admin/ban-country-ip.php

CONTENT
HERE IS GETTING THE COUNTRY list with checkbox in the admin backend

```
<?php
    $countryiso = mysql_query("SELECT distinct country_name as country_name FROM location_country");
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<th>Country</th><th> Add/Remove </th>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countryiso)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['country_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

AND in the frond end registration it ECHO's them in registration.php.

```
$ctrstr="";
$res=mysql_query("select *  from location_country where code NOT IN('A1','A2','AP','EU') order by name");
$ctrstr.="<select name=\"country\" id=\"country\" onChange=\"loadState();\"  >
        <option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">-Select Country-</option>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
    if($country==$row[0])
    $ctrstr.="<option value=\"$row[0]\" selected>$row[1]</option>";
    else
    $ctrstr.="<option value=\"$row[0]\">$row[1]</option>";
}
$ctrstr.="</select>";
```

I would like to know how can i hide a value from a select list using checkbox. When i un-check in the back-end a country, it should also be removed in the front end in the select field. If i check it again, should be showing again. I want to mention that the countries are stocked in mysql in a column.

MYSQL - TABLE STRUCTURE

```
#   Name    Type            Collation    Attributes Null    Default Extra
1   code    varchar(2)    utf8_unicode_ci       No      
2   name    varchar(255)    utf8_unicode_ci     No
```

Comment: When you remove any country from back-end you save the list of removed countries ? show the logic how you are saving the removed or added country list in the back-end

Comment: I was thinking somehow on adding another column and in the column to have values 1 for checked countries and 0 for not checked countries. But there are lots of things to do that i could not find and don't know: In this case i will need to update the value from mysql when i check and un-check and after add somehow an if condition like: if value of the selected country is 0 then hide country from select field in front end. Sorry i am a bit of a noob in this.

Comment: Yes you can do it its simple just save the countries with 1 that are checked from back-end and on front end just query them like  `select *  from location_country where code NOT IN('A1','A2','AP','EU') AND your_new_column =1 order by name` thats all for the front end only you  have to build the update/add functionality with your_new_column

Comment: @dianuj ah, great idea, one thing how do i update values in mysql with checkbox? To change value in the your_new_column when i check and uncheck.

Comment: Let me give you example but its not complete make a form put the checkbox with name `countries[]` array `<input type="checkbox" name="countries[]">` get all the posted values from the form first update all the country's `your_new_column` to 0 then loop through the posted values and update   `your_new_column` to 1 hope you got my idea

Comment: Got the idea, but because of my limited knowledge in php mysql don't know how to attache this do my own code.

Comment: @dianuj Could you please add an answer based on my code. I tried yestarday and today and did not got it :(

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery you can do that to hide option from list:

Add ID attribute to checkbox   :

```
<input type="checkbox" id='hide'>
```

jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#hide").click(function(){ 
          if( $("#hide:checked").length == 1 ) {
            $("#country option[value='1']").hide();
           }  else {
              $("#country option[value='1']").show();
           }
         });
      });

</script>
```

And if you want to print this script using PHP :

```
$script = '<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#hide").click(function(){ 
        if( $("#hide:checked").length == 1 ) {     alert($("#hide:checked").length);
$("#country option[value=1]").hide();
       } else {
           $("#country option[value=1]").show();
       }
    });
  });

    </script>';
echo $script;
```

Comment: Are this answer help you to solving your problem?

Comment: And exactly where and how do i add this?

Comment: But it's not possible to integrate it in my php. Don't see how.

Comment: Please see the Answer after edited , and print this script in your page , and include the jQuery library in your head script.